# Where should I transform data extracted froom a room database in a MVVM before showing them to a recycler view?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I have an android app in kotlin with a room database, with a modelView/reposoritory , my app create encrypted file and the path of these file are stored in the database and if I decrypt these file I get a String that I then put in a recyclerView (One table contains 4 file path, the first file represent a title )

I wanted to know where should I decrrypt these file before sending the decryptedString, should I use something like a @TypeConverter ? or in the modelView before sending the string to my recycler view ?

I'm really trying to apply good programming practice

Also I used live Data but since I only store the path to the data and not the actual data inside I'm not sure if this was a good idea...

I'm a beginner so any key word would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to make the transformation inside the ViewModel.
TypeConverter is not required for above use case.

TypeConverters are used to store a custom data type whose value you would like to store in a single database column. To add this kind of support for custom types, you provide a TypeConverter, which converts a custom class to and from a known type that Room can persist.
**For e.g.** to store a Date in Room Database.

I am happy to read that you are applying good programming practice in your app.

Please see below details:

1. UI (Activity / Fragment) should take only **UI related** decisions.
2. View Model should take **Data related** decisions, calculations, manipulation's and transformations
3. Repository should take care of sourcing data from multiple sources (Network, Local Database, etc) and maintain it appropriately
4. And finally your Data Source, in your case your Room Database should only and only take the responsibility of storing and retrieving data.

Hence, please try to use **View Model** for your data manipulations related to encryption and decryption.